# How to handle a title edit (change) made to make the question fit a specific answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

*(Preface, this is **not** mainly about the question in question (sic) - or its editor, but the general handling of such changes. The question change initiating this is just a great example for the issue and how it may affect our workings)*

I just stumbled across the change of a question's title that not only changed its meaning in fundamental ways, but also made it quite snugly fit a previous written answer. [The question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8134)'s original title read:

**What limited the use of the Z8000 in personal computers?**

clearly asking about *Z8000* and *personal computers*. It got changed into:

**What limited the use of the Z8000 (vs. 68K and 8086) CPU for 16-bit computers?**

Now changing the very core of the question from personal computers to generic computing confined to 16 bits and introducing arbitrary other CPUs as direct references of which only one (68k) was mentioned in the question, while the other never was.

I do consider the change substantial in context of what the question is asking.

Changes that drastic can invalidate and marginalize answers that did (as they should) focus on what has been originally asked.

The fact that he change was made by the author of an otherwise well formed, reasonable and informative answer did trigger my assumption that here some retroactive editing happened. No doubt, this may well be unintentional by the editor, as it reflects his own interpretation/wording of what is asked. Still, it's way more than just a clarification in wording. Isn't it?

I feel it's very important that answers should stay true to what has been asked, so changing questions is a very delicate matter to be handled with extreme caution.

So, how to handle this?

(And no in advance, an answer's author not objecting to a change isn't the same as approval.)

Answer (score 1):

If an edit to the question changes the question's scope, it has to have a pretty good reason. Otherwise it will be reverted. An answerer *is* allowed to do this, but they must have a good enough reason.

I'm not sure of the reason for the change in your example.